# Drop down menu won't work with MasterPage

Tags: html, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages

So I am facing that problem for couple of days now and I really don't know where to start with this issue...

When I am trying to create the  [hover DropDownMenu](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)
It just won't work with the other stuff goes on my CSS file.
it shows the button itself (half of it) and when you hover. it does change his color but nothing really happends. 
No list opened.
[Picture of it](http://prntscr.com/dw1g27)

(The CSS copied from the w3s School code they offer)

Thanks for helping!
Hope to hear from you guys soon.

The MasterPage Code:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
    <title>Nua </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />



    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        .topleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 9%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.topLeftSecond {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 17.5%;
    font-size: 16px;

}

</style>

            
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

      
        <% if (Session["Level"].ToString().Equals("-1"))
            { %>              
        <div class="icon-bar">
                  <a class="active" href="HomePage.aspx"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
                 <a href="Login.aspx">Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a> 
                   <a href="Register.aspx">Register <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> 
                     <a class="more" href="HomePage.aspx#main">About  <i class="fa fa-info-circle"> </i></a>

</div>



    <%} %> 
      <%--  This is the Drop down menu code--%>
    
             <%if (Session["Level"].ToString().Equals("1"))
               { %>
                             <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="dropbtn">Here</button>
                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                      <a href="AdminArea.aspx">Link 1</a>
                                      <a href="WorkersPage.aspx">Link 2</a>
                         </div>
                    </div>



              <%} %>
         
    <div>
      
           <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope I posted it right O-o

Comment: any html and css code?

Comment: The Css code is too long to upload it here :/

Comment: Please use then http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apmWBz (This is it? No clue about the Javascript. I am suppose to do a school project here and the teacher just wants us to copy things from her. Huge thanks for help tho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. For `.dropdown` set `display: inline-block` - now it has full page width
2. For `.dropdown .dropbtn` set `height: auto` - now it gets 32px from styles for `button`
3. You lost below code, which shows menu on hover:

   ```
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
       display: block;
   }
   ```

Comment: Using your answer below: 1. It not exist, your `.dropdown` element is `div`, not `li`, so rule `li.dropdown` wouldn't work. 2. `.dropdown .dropbtn` is your button, I have no idea what you couldn't understand here. 3. You forgot to add this small piece of code I pasted here.

Comment: Hey!
Huge thanks!!!
I simply have no clue about these stuff and what they do. as I said earlier. 
No one teaching me these and I am just trying to understand what I am doing while actually doing it (Lack of time a little bit)

Can you please explain me what's the difference between div and li?

Comment: `div` is a block element, let's say it is something like rectangle to keep content ;) `li` is a list element (like lists in MS office) - it should be inside list container like for example `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Answer (score 0):

Lost you my friend.

1. .dropdown Display : inline-block - is already exist (?)
2. what .dropdown .dropbtn?
3. I lost code?

   This is the DropdownMenu CSS code.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #555;
}

li {
    float: left;
    
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

You mean the code you just write down

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

I need to add that to this code above ^^?

Thanks for help tho!
please explain.